# ASP.NET: Proper way of exporting GridView to Excel including dynamically added rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview, export

I've been attempting to implement a simple method for exporting GridViews to Excel sheets. However, I'm stuck on this one for quite a while now:

My `GridView` has `AutoGenerateColumns` set to `true`, as the datasource is dynamic and not really predictable (changing number of columns over time). The `HeaderRow` it automatically creates is not suitable for me, hence I've also set `ShowHeader` to `false` and created my own in `OnRowCreated` event, like this:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header) {

        gv.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, GetHeader());
        gv.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(1, GetSubHeader());


}
```

where `GetHeader()` and `GetSubHeader()` both return a `GridViewRow` (there are two rows in the header using different colspans, rowspans and stuff). This all works nicely on the website, however, when I try to export the `GridView` using OpenXML like this:

```
    ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage();
    var workSheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("List 1");
    var totalCols = gv.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
    var totalRows = gv.Rows.Count;
    var headerRow = gv.HeaderRow;

    for (int i = 0; i < totalCols; i++) {

        workSheet.Cells[1,i+1].Value = headerRow.Cells[i].Text;

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < totalCols; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < totalRows; j++) {

            workSheet.Cells[j+2,i+1].Value = gv.Rows[j].Cells[i].Text;

        }

    }

    return excel;
```

what I get is a table with the original HeaderRow that is hidden - I've figured I should skip the first cycle obviously - and then the rows with actual data. No trace of the two rows I added in `OnRowCreated`.

Could anybody please explain why this is happening and how I can work this out? The method should ideally always export the entire GridView as it is displayed on the website.

Note: The other way using HtmlTextWriter and `GridView.RenderControl()` is probably not an option since I wasn't even able to open the file in Excel after downloading (OpenOffice did fine though) and then I read somewhere that the sheets aren't actually usable for data processing, which in this case is crucial.

EDIT: After I added the two `HeaderRow`s in `OnRowDataBound` instead of `OnRowCreated`, the loop accounts for them, however all that gets into the worksheet are blank fields and it also seems that they are not taken into account by `gv.Rows.Count`, as the loop never gets to the last two rows in my table.

I tried debugging and and indeed all that is returned by `gv.Rows[j].Cells[i].Text;` is a `""`, even though the cells have their `Text` property set up AND the table displays OK on the website.

I find this behavior very confusing, I guess I'm missing something big. Could anybody tell my why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't matter if it is autogenerated or otherwise. The trick is to treat everything as an object and a child of an object. Then using the object's properties (and also Excel's), you can then do the manipulation of the data in the gridview.

See sample code below

```
protected void ExportToExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        //To Export all pages
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        this.BindGrid();
        GridView1.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
        foreach (TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
        {
            cell.BackColor = GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
        }
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            row.BackColor = Color.White;
            foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
                {
                    cell.BackColor = GridView1.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.BackColor = GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor;
                }
                cell.CssClass = "textmode";
            }
        }
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
        //style to format numbers to string
        string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
        Response.Write(style);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

This is just one of the ways to go.

There are many other samples. Just google Gridview to Excel.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but as I've mentioned above, this is not working as Excel refuses to open  the downloaded file. OpenOffice opens it without problems though, which is quite baffling to me o_o.

Comment: I see from your code that you are using the ExcelPackage class. If your code works, try using the Excel class. And as i said, my answer  is just one way to go. There r many other examples. Just do a search.